# Named tuple with less-than operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following implementation for the `__lt__`. Could you please check if it's okay to compare objects like that?

```
class Record(NamedTuple):
    video_id: str
    uuid: Optional[UUID]
    mac: Optional[str]
    s3_bucket: str
    s3_key: str
    reference_date: date

    @staticmethod
    def _lt(a: Any, b: Any) -> bool:
        if a and b:
            return a < b
        if a is None and b:
            return True
        return False

    def __lt__(self, other: "Record") -> Union[bool, Type["NotImplementedType"]]:
        if not isinstance(other, Record):
            return NotImplemented
        for field in self._fields:
            self_ = getattr(self, field)
            other_ = getattr(other, field)
            if self_ == other_:
                continue
            return self._lt(self_, other_)
        return False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code is dangerous:

```py
        if a and b:
            return a < b
        if a is None and b:
            return True
        return False
```

Consider `a = -1` and `b = 0`.  `a and b` is `False` because `b` is falsey, so `a < b` is never computed.

Since `a is None` is false, we skip to `return False`, yielding a surprising result for `Record._lt(-1, 0)`

You should explicitly test `a is not None and b is not None` instead of `a and b`.

Based on your typing, it currently doesn’t look like you’d pass in an `int` or a `float`, but if the class changes in the future, or is used as the model for another similar class, the unexpected behaviour might arise.

Comment: what do you think about using @dataclass(order=True) instead of custom __lt__ method?

Comment: A `@dataclass` is mutable (assuming `frozen=True` is not specified), where as tuples, including `NamedTuple`, are immutable.  Without knowing more about the class and it's intended usages, it is hard to give a definitive answer.  I like both `@dataclass` and `NamedTuple`, but they are different animals used for different things.

Answer (score 4):

1. No code is always more correct than yes code.  `NamedTuple` has comparison.

Unless one has a good reason to [surprise the user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) with other than the perfectly good built-in behavior, in which case they would document that reason clearly, this is far from OK.

2. You *may* want to use a [`dataclass`](https://rmcomplexity.com/article/2021/01/04/everything-you-need-to-know-about-dataclasses.html#data-classes-that-we-can-compare-and-order) instead, which supports type annotations better:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(order=True)
class Record:
    video_id: str
    uuid: Optional[UUID]
    mac: Optional[str]
    s3_bucket: str
    s3_key: str
    reference_date: date
```

-- EDIT --

It's always good to describe the intent in code, by means of a (unit-) test script.

An example:

```py
assert Record("myvid", None, None) < Record("yourvid", None, None)
assert Record("id", s3_key="a/b/c") < Record("id", s3_key="a/b/x")
try:
  Record("id") < Record(None)
else:
  raise AssertionError("should have raised")
...
```

Comment: Does default comparison works the same as mine?

Comment: for example, how to compare int and None?

Comment: I advise to write a simple test script to clarify your intent.  I'll edit a hint to that in my answer.

Comment: so it's necessary to write a custom comparator because the exception will be thrown and we don't know what to return true or false

Comment: Wait - do you _need_ to have a 'NotImplemented' as result (as in `if compare(a, b) == NotImplemented`)?

Then don't hijack the `__lt__`, but define a dedicated function for this.   Else users will definitely be surprised by this unexpected behavior.

If you _need_ the `a<b` to raise, you're good to go with the default implementation.